# How to disable Ctrl+Alt+Delete on Debian 9 (Stretch)?

Tags: linux, debian, security

I'm using Debian 9 (Stretch) and I read that for security reasons, it's preferable to disable the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> keys combination.

However, I looked over some tutorials that says to comment some line on the /etc/init/control-alt-delete.conf file, but can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 4):

Jessie/stretch is built on the systemd style boot and there is no more /etc/inittab. The behavior is controlled by /lib/systemd/system/ctrl-alt-del.target (not /etc/systemd/system/*): Type

```
  ls -la /lib/systemd/system/ctrl*

  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Aug 30 23:04 /lib/systemd/system/ctrl-alt-del.target -> reboot.target
```

To change this we need to remove the current link and replace:

```
> sudo rm /lib/systemd/system/ctrl-alt-del.target 
> sudo ln -s /dev/null /lib/systemd/system/ctrl-alt-del.target 
> sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

...so to disable Ctrl-Alt-Del we point the target to /dev/null i.e. to be completely ignored and again the last command 're-reads' the configuration and applies the change.